Locating a transcript of a Jonathan Edwards' handwritten sermon entitled "To The Children."
I'm trying to locate a transcript of Jonathan Edwards's sermon from August 1740 that he delivered to the children of his congregation. I have already located a facsimile of the handwritten manuscript but it is fairly illegible and I don't want to have to buy the entire volume 22 of Jonathan Edwards' works in which the sermon transcript is located.

Thank you for this link which enabled to find exactly what I was searching for when I provided the sermon title!

Yale has a JEC (Jonathan Edwards Center) that lets you search the volumes
Clicking Browse the Collection > Sermons and Discourses, 1739-1742 (WJE Online Vol. 22), then scrolling down to The Sermon > Children Ought to Love the Lord Jesus Christ Above All should have what you are looking for.
As in the manuscript facsimile, the sermon has a Doctrine section (starting at middle of facsimile page 2) and an Application section (starting at middle of facsimile page 13).
The WJE Vol 22  also includes a background introduction for that sermon.

This is a valuable link to bookmark. Thanks

yes, very valuable link.  Thank you.

Again, thank you!
